# Semantic Similarity Result interpretation

Tags: semantics, wordnet

I'm performing a semantic similarity using a tool here,

I'm getting the following results, but cannot properly interprete them:

```
apple#n#1,banana#n#1    0.04809463683080774
apple#n#1,banana#n#2    0.13293629283742603
apple#n#2,banana#n#1    0.0
apple#n#2,banana#n#2    0.0
```

here is the code:

```
URL url = new URL ( "file" , null , "dictionary/3.0/dict" );
        IDictionary dict = new Dictionary ( url ) ;
        dict.open () ;

        // look up first sense of the word " dog "
        IIndexWord idxWord = dict . getIndexWord ( "dog" , POS.NOUN ) ;
        IWordID wordID = idxWord . getWordIDs () . get (0) ; // 1 st meaning
        List <IWordID> wordIDs = idxWord.getWordIDs();


        JWS ws= new JWS ("dictionary", "3.0");


        TreeMap <String,Double> scores1 = ws.getJiangAndConrath().jcn("apple", "banana", "n");
        for (String s:scores1.keySet())
            System.out.println(s+"\t"+scores1.get(s));
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [NLTK Documentation:](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/howto/wordnet.html)

> The Jiang Conrath similarity returns a score denoting how similar two
>   word senses are, based on the Information Content (IC) of the Least
>   Common Subsumer (most specific ancestor node) and that of the two
>   input Synsets. The relationship is given by the equation 1 / (IC(s1) +
>   IC(s2) - 2 * IC(lcs)).

A result of 0 means that the two concepts are not related at all.
A result near 1 would mean a very close relationship.

Answer (score 0):

can you put me code source written in JAVA responsible for the execution of LeacockAndChodorow algorithm because I do have some problems with Url variable?